# Edit /Update entered data stored in database - servlet

Tags: java, database, servlets, database-connectivity

I have made a servlet file iin which I have added insertion, deletion and viewingthe data from database.

Now I want to add updation of inserted data but I am not able to complete it. As I have added whole code in single file I dont know how to add it. can any one help me with it ??
Waiting for reply.

```
        if(req.getParameter("choise")!=null)    {
            nm = req.getParameter("choise");

            idr = "UPDATE student SET rollno = ?, class = ?, mobileno = ? WHERE name ='"+nm+"'";

            try {
                st=con.createStatement();
                int rs1 = st.executeUpdate(idr);
                pwinsert.println(rs1);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.getMessage();
                System.out.println("Error " +e);
            }

            System.out.println("Data Edited...");

        }
```

Comment: How about you give us the update method you have written so far, and the html form that invokes it.

Comment: it looks like you are using PreparedStatment syntax with a normal Statement. where do rollNo, class and mobileNo come from?

Comment: @BevynQ
Sir, this is my code, can you please help me to add update feaure ??


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16998126/update-edit-entered-data-from-database-servlet

Answer (score 0):

You can create different Servlet's for each CRUD Operation. Either using flag variable also you can recognize which CRUD operation to follow, but this is not good practice. Check this [link](https://www.classle.net/content-page/crud-operations-using-mvc)

Comment: I had already shared link. You can refer it and make necessary changes as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(req.getParameter("choise")!=null)    {
            nm = req.getParameter("choise");
            if(nm.equals("UPDATE")){ idr = "UPDATE student SET rollno = ?, class = ?, mobileno = ? WHERE name ='"+nm+"'";

            try {
                st=con.createStatement();
                int rs1 = st.executeUpdate(idr);
                pwinsert.println(rs1);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.getMessage();
                System.out.println("Error " +e);
            }

            System.out.println("Data Edited...");



}else if(nm.equals("ADD")){

idr = "<INSERT QUERY>";

            try {
                st=con.createStatement();
                int rs1 = st.executeQuery(idr);
                pwinsert.println(rs1);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.getMessage();
                System.out.println("Error " +e);
            }

            System.out.println("Data inserted...");


}


        }
```

Comment: nice but sir can you please help me on this ??
       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16998126/update-edit-entered-data-from-database-servlet

Wanna add the  EDIT funcctionality......

Answer (score 0):

this should do what you want

```
String nm = req.getParameter("name");
String roll = req.getParameter("roll");
String clas = req.getParameter("clas");
String mono = req.getParameter("mono");

if(req.getParameter("choise")!=null)    {
    nm = req.getParameter("choise");

    idr = "UPDATE student SET rollno = ?, class = ?, mobileno = ? WHERE name = ?";

    try {
        PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement(idr);
        pst.setString(1,roll);
        pst.setString(2,class);
        pst.setString(3,mono);
        pst.setString(4,nm);

        int rs1 = st.executeUpdate(idr);
        pwinsert.println(rs1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
        System.out.println("Error " +e);
    }

    System.out.println("Data Edited...");

}
```

I suggest you start breaking you code into methods for instance.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
        throws IOException, ServletException    {

    String nm = req.getParameter("name");
    String roll = req.getParameter("roll");
    String clas = req.getParameter("clas");
    String mono = req.getParameter("mono");

    Connection conn = getDatabaseConnection();
    Statement sql = createSqlStatement(conn, nm ,roll, clas, mono);

    processSqlStatement(conn,sql);

    createOutput(req,res);

}
```

It will make it a lot easier for you to maintain and add new things.